# Object reference not set to an instance of an object while reading file properties from SP2010

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, nullreferenceexception

I have sharepoint document library which has custom field called "DocumentType" this is not mandatory field. When I am trying to read this property using the below code, when value is there in this field its working fine but where its value empty giving the error **"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."** If value is not there I need to pass empty string for further logic, how can I handle this?

```
SPFile spFile=Web.GetFile(Context.Request.Url.ToString());
string spDocumentType=string.Empty;
if (spFile.Properties["DocumentType"].ToString() == "INV") *In this line exception throwing where value is empty in this field in the doc library.
{
spDocumentType = spFile.Properties["DocumentType"].ToString();
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do like this:

```
if(spFile.Properties["DocumentType"] !=null)
 {
   spDocumentType = spFile.Properties["DocumentType"].ToString() == "INV" ? spFile.Properties["DocumentType"].ToString() : "";

 }
else
{
spDocumentType ="";

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this piece of code:

```
spFile.Properties["DocumentType"].ToString()
```

To this:

```
Convert.ToString(spFile.Properties["DocumentType"])
```

While `ToString()` throws the exception you're getting when the value is `null`, the [`Convert.ToString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.tostring.aspx) method tests for `null` and returns an empty string.

Comment: The above both the answer are correct, but its not allowing to accept both the answer.